# postgres parse json to find compatible entries

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL I created a table with a `JSON` type column

```
id,country_code
11767,{"country_code": [{"code": "GB01F290/00", "new": 1}, {"code": "DE08F290/00", "new": 1}, {"code": "GB02F290/00", "new": 1}]}
11768,{"country_code": [{"code": "GB01F290/20", "new": 1}, {"code": "GB20F290/23", "new": 1}]}
```

`list = ["GB01F290/00", "GB21F290/41"]`

How can I `select` the rows that country_code:code contains any element of the list?

Comment: There are several ways to do it, but they all will involve transforming your data or your query into some other format.  What tools would you like to use to do that transformation?  You could do it purely in SQL, but that is not likely to be the best way.

Comment: @jjanes do you mean using `cast` and some regex to do it? for now I am using python to do it but I know it can be done in psql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a way to create a [jsonpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) query to do this, but you would need some way to transform your `["GB01F290/00", "GB21F290/41"]` into the correct jsonpath.  I'm not very good at jsonpath, so I won't go into that.

Another way to do this would be to use the `@>` operator with the `ANY(...)` construct.  But that takes a PostgreSQL array of jsonb documents as its right-hand-side, and each document needs to have a specific structure to match the structure of the documents you are querying.  One way to express that array of jsonb would be:

```
'{"{\"country_code\": [{\"code\": \"GB01F290/00\"}]}","{\"country_code\": [{\"code\": \"GB21F290/41\"}]}"}'::jsonb[]
```

Or another way, with less obnoxious quoting/escaping would be:

```
ARRAY['{"country_code": [{"code": "GB01F290/00"}]}'::jsonb,' {"country_code": [{"code": "GB21F290/41"}]}']
```

A way to obtain that value given your input would be with this query:

```
select array_agg(jsonb_build_object(
   'country_code',
   jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object( 'code', x))
 )) from 
 jsonb_array_elements('["GB01F290/00", "GB21F290/41"]')
```

But there might be better ways of doing that, in python.

Then the query would be:

```
select * from thetable where country_code @> ANY($1::jsonb[])
```

Where $1 holds the value given in the first block, or the result of the expression given in the 2nd block or the result of the query given in the third block. You could also put combine the queries into one by putting the first into the second as a subquery, but that might inhibit use of indexes.

Note that the column country_code needs to be of type jsonb, not json, for this to work.  But that is what it should be anyway.

It would probably be better if you chose a different way to store your data in the first place.  An array of objects where each object has a unique name (the value of "code", here) is an antipattern, and should instead be an object of objects, with the unique name being the key.  And having objects which just have one key at the top level, which is the same as the name of the column, is another antipattern.  And what is the point of `"new":1` if it is always present (or is that just an artifact of the example you chose)?  Does it convey any meaning?  And if you remove all of that stuff, you are left with just a list of strings.  Why use jsonb in the first place for that?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, at first I wasn't sure what keys would be present in the json object, but I believe it would be better (easier to search) if I create a new table to store each country_code dict with a FK to the main data.